# Execute webpack compiled bundle in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, server-side-rendering

I want to implement server-side rendering for my ReactJS app. I use `react-router`. I take `routes.js` as webpack entry point and compile with `output.libraryTarget = "commonjs2"` option. Then I require the result of compilation in NodeJS script to make rendering. But I've got en error.
Webpack wrap modules in following code:

```
/* 277 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(Buffer, global) {
    if (global.foo) {
        /* ... */
    }
    /* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, __webpack_require__(277).Buffer, (function() { return this; }())))

 /***/ }
```

When NodeJS tries to execute `(function() { return this; }())` its return `undefined`. In browser it will return `window`. Why webpack use such wrap code? How to make this code works in NodeJS?

I use [node-clone](https://github.com/pvorb/node-clone) as external lib. It don't use any other libs as dependency. But webpack in its bundle makes [buffer](https://github.com/feross/buffer) as a dependency for this lib. And inside the `buffer` code I've got en error `Cannot read property 'TYPED_ARRAY_SUPPORT' of undefined`. It happens because in nodeJS `(function() { return this; }())` return `undefined`.

Comment: Have you tried `target: 'node'` in your webpack config?

Comment: That is exactly what I looking for :) Thanks @JoshDavidMiller

Comment: Great! I put this as an answer below so we can let others know it is solved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, webpack will package things up for browsers. If you want to build Node libraries with webpack, you need to specifiy a [`target`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) in your configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...

  target: 'node',
};
```